# What version am I supposed to be passing to Paypal for NVP requests?

Tags: api, paypal

I'm trying to do an NVP API request for express checkout, but I can't figure out what API version to user.  I've specified VERSION=92.0, VERSION=91.0, and a few others but all of those give me an invalid version error back from the sandbox.

What is a valid api version to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

89.0 was their last major release about a month and a half ago.
It looks like the latest developer guide was published a few days early. I don't think 92 is out yet.

If you use 89.0 you'll be more than fine.

Comment: You can find the latest available version at any time by opening the WSDL at http://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl and checking the latest ns:version.

Comment: It was updated from 89.0 to 92.0 between the time Lenny Markus posted his response, and I posted my comment. :-)